# Concerned about 240v outlet in my garage. Says 20 amp 250 volt, but inside the box only two wires are connected to the breakers?

Tags: electrical, fire

It has two adjacent 20 amp breakers, with one wire from each going to the receptacle. There appears to be a thin ground wire coming out of the insulation inside the breaker box, but it is not attached to anything? My old air compressor was 110v, and the new one on the way is 240v but wants a 30 amp breaker? I have a feeling this old 240v outlet is a fire waiting to happen with two hots, no neutral and no ground. How concerned should I be. The man who outfitted this garage died in 1986, so I have no way to ask him about it.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at both ends, as well as any markings visible on the wiring or cable jacket?

Comment: I don't want to call an electrician over, and have him freak out and report it to the powers that be. Everything in the garage seems to work and not have any problems for the 20 years I have lived here, I just need a 240 volt 30 amp receptacle that won't burn down the garage.

Comment: Either that, or have it hard wired into the box, if possible, and maybe remove the bad outlet entirely.

Comment: Images are too large of course, except the one of the outlet.

Comment: No visible markings on the cable, it is very old, and dark grey shiny looking insulation. I mean really, what the hell good are phone cameras, if every picture they take is 8 freaking MB

Comment: Oh screw it, just going to call an electrician... Deal with the aftermath later I guess.

Comment: Maybe bring the image into your PC, open in an image editing program, and save it again but reduce the JPEG quality to 3.  Most phones save pictures with quality=12 and the files are enormous to no useful purpose.

Comment: Or, you can manually upload the pictures to imgur.com and post the links here. Someone will embed them for you. But, calling in an electrician won't hurt. Also, he won't "freak out and report you" - that serves no purpose for him. He'll happily charge you to fix this and any other issues he finds and can talk you into paying for.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the nameplate data on the compressor to determine the size of breaker it requires.

- There is generally a "minimum breaker", either stated or found by multiplying FLA (Full Load Amps) x 125% and rounding up to the next available breaker size.
- Then there is a "maximum breaker" stated on the nameplate.

Any size within that range will suffice. If 20A is an allowable size, it can be on this circuit once its deficiencies if any are corrected.

---

Grounds: If the wires entirely transit a **metal conduit** which is non-flexible... or is flexible and has a ground strap that ties to the connector... then the metal conduit **is the valid grounding path**.

Otherwise a ground wire is warranted. 20A circuits require a 12 AWG Copper ground.
25-60A circuits require a 10 AWG copper or 8 AWG aluminum ground.

If the ground is defective, but the box was installed legally at the time, it is legal to "retrofit a ground".  Otherwise new cable would need to be run.

---

Neutrals: It is perfectly fine for the circuit to not have a neutral.   240V loads don't need it. Your main air conditioner, water heater, EV charger, pump, sauna, you name it - none of them have neutrals.  No need for it if the appliance doesn't have any 120V loads.  This would apply to any compressor.

---

Other than ground, a 3-wire "NEMA 6-20" or "L6-20" type receptacle only has 2 wires, and they are both hot, and this is normal.  A 6-20 looks exactly like a normal receptacle, except with one of the blades turned sideways.

---

On 240v-only loads with no neutral, it is perfectly OK to "build-a-breaker" using two 120V single breakers. **Code requires the breakers be "handle-tied"** with a listed handle-tie.   It's possible it had one and it crumbled from age.

The handle-tie does not provide any mechanism for "common trip" so if one side trips, it's possible the other side won't trip.  That is fine for these loads.  The main purpose of the handle tie is to assure the maintainer shuts both sides off.

Comment: It's *common* for 240V loads to have neutral, anyway, just in case you need it later, right?

Comment: @user253751 Depends on who's doing the work. A contractor or builder will usually go the cheapest path, which would be two wire if only two wire is needed. In essence, having the neutral for future potential use is wise, but not necessarily common.

Comment: @stevieb no, the hot wires are for potential use, neutral is for *non*-potential use :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 different issues:

- Wire Size vs. Breaker Size

It is a reasonable assumption (though never a guarantee) that the existing wire is 12 AWG, sized appropriately for a 20A breaker. If that's the case, you will need new wire for a 30A circuit. There is a small possibility you have 10 AWG wire, in which case you can reuse it with a 20A breaker.

- Neutral Wire

You do *not* need a neutral wire for a 240V-only circuit. Typically a clothes dryer or oven needs neutral but a water heater or compressor does not. The only way to tell for sure is to look at the installation instructions for the new compressor. Neutral - or lack thereof - is *not* a safety issue, except when mixed up with ground.

- Ground Wire

This may be a real problem. If you need to replace the other wires then you add a ground as part of the replacement (e.g., a 10 AWG 2-wires plus ground cable). If you don't need to replace the other wires, you can add a ground separately. If your wires are running through metal conduit (I doubt it based on the wording of the question) then the metal conduit acts as the ground.

No ground wire may have been legal when the circuit was originally installed, but it is not legal now, at least once you start making changes to it.

- Hardwire vs. Receptacle

Hardwiring has certain advantages. In particular, it avoids the need for GFCI under newer versions of the NEC. That is more of a life-safety issue than a fire issue. Personally, I like hardwiring devices when practical, as there is one less thing to go wrong. But that has no real effect on the questions of wire size, neutral wire and ground wire.

Comment: Interesting, I am pretty sure the compressors are generally white/black/green, three wires?

Comment: And yes, zero conduit in the house or garage. Built in 1946 or so. GI Bill just after WWII. Stand alone garage was added around 1973 or so.

Comment: I think I will just call an electrician, as much as I hate to. The fusebox is a huge Square D thing from the old days, with 20 breakers in it. Possibly industrial quality even, I imagine having it hardwired, it will require bolting the compressor to the slab. Not a huge deal, but I imagine it would be very bad if it somehow fell over while hardwired.

Comment: Basically I know nothing about electrical, but I don't want to get in some sort of code mess, and have some guy I am paying to work on it, tell me he can't , and still charge to tell me the whole garage has to be rewired. I am not rich by any means.

Comment: @Miguello, you only need to bring the circuit you are working on to code.  Otherwise no one could have electrical work done without their entire house having to be rewired to the latest code spec.

Comment: @TigerGuy Generally speaking, you are correct. The exception would be if an electrician finds a clear & present danger, which is not *likely*, but is possible.

Comment: @Miguello, "compressors are generally white/black/green", yes, _if_ they run on 120V. Since yours is 240V it could be black/black/green(bare) or red/black/green(bare).

Comment: @freeman depends on cable vs conduit. Cable black/white. Conduit 2 blacks or black/red.